# How to use a theme installed with melpa?

Tags: package-repositories

I want to use this theme: https://github.com/jonnay/emagicians-starter-kit/blob/master/themes/org-beautify-theme.org

I installed it via `list-package` successfully.

I tried loading it via `load-theme RET org-beautify RET` but it says `Unable to find theme file for org-beautify`. So I add `~\.emacs.d\elpa\org-beautify-theme-20150106.956` to my `'custom-theme-load-path` and do the `load-theme` thing again, this time it says `Undefined custom theme`.

How can I activate the theme?

Seeing as someone marked my thread as a duplicate: my custom-theme-load-path does not reset after calling load-theme. You can see that after setting `custom-theme-load-path` to the location of the file, calling `load-theme RET org-beautify RET` does not give the response `Unable to find theme file...` anymore. Instead, I get an error of a different sort ("Undefined custom theme"), which makes me think that I'm not installing it properly. Why can't I choose the theme from Options->Customize Emacs->Custom Themes in the first place after installing it with melpa?

Comment: It looks like this is an error in the package itself.  I propose a few ways to fix it below.  I wonder if whoever packaged this up for MELPA even tried installing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the author of the theme is using `org-babel` to invoke the theme, rather than the `M-x load-theme`.  The way that custom themes usually work is that there is a theme named `foo` within a file called `foo-theme.el`.  In the case of `org-beautify`, the actual theme is called `org-beautify-theme` when it should just be named `org-beautify`.

There are two ways to fix this problem:

1. Within the file `org-beautify-theme.el` there are three references in code to `org-beautify-theme`.  Change all of those to `org-beautify`
2. Rename the file `org-beautify-theme.el` to `org-beautify-theme-theme.el`

I would recommend that you contact the author so that the problem gets fixed upstream.

Comment: nispio, thank you for getting to the root of the problem. I tried the other suggestions, and while it did work for other themes, it did not work for this particular one. Now I know why. I went with option #2, by the way. It's working nicely now. Thank you. I contacted the author about the problem.

Comment: It did not do the magic for me. I do not know where it went wrong :-(

Comment: @Prasanna The numbered items in the answer are an either/or.  Do either 1 or 2, but not both.  Is that the problem?

Comment: I understood. But both the options did not do any trick.